# How does transform-style: preserve-3d work with this card flip example, and in general?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I was following along with this video about making a card flip effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV8MVmtgmoY&ab_channel=ArjunKhara

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>card flip</title>
    <style>
        .maincontainer {
            position: relative;
            width: 250px;
            height: 320px;
        }

        .thecard {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: all 3s ease;
        }

        .thecard:hover {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

        .thefront {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            background: yellow;
            color: darkgrey;
            border-radius: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .theback {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            background: blue;
            color: darkgrey;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 20px;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="maincontainer">
        <div class="thecard">
            <div class="thefront">front of card</div>
            <div class="theback">back of card</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the front of the card:

[image: front of card]

Here is the back of the card when `transform-style: preserve-3d;` is enabled:

[image: back with preserve-3d]

Here is the back of the card when `transform-style: preserve-3d;` is commented out:

[image: back without preserve-3d]

On https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style it says:

`transform-style: flat` : Indicates that the children of the element are lying in the plane of the element itself.

`transform-style: preserve-3d` : Indicates that the children of the element should be positioned in the 3D-space.

But I am still confused. When I comment the line out(making it flat by default", why does the yellow card show it's back after hovering and rotating? Where is the blue card after the rotation? I don't quite understand what exactly it means for the children to be "lying in the plane of the element itself".

Answer (score 0):

Without 3D transform-style , the faces of the card would be flattened with its parents, and the back face's rotation would be nullified. To position the faces in 3D space we'll need to reset their positions in 2D.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).